# Kotlin project saving a black image instead of capturing a photo

Tags: kotlin

I want when I click on the button in the layout to take a photo and save it in the files, but the problem is that it's saving a black screen instead of the photo. How can I correct that ?

This the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".qrscanner.ScannerActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnCapture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <net.simplifiedcoding.mlkitsample.facedetector.FaceBoxOverlay
        android:id="@+id/graphic_overlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnCapture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Capture"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the FaceDetectionActivity.

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.mlkitsample.facedetector

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetection
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetector
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetectorOptions
import net.simplifiedcoding.mlkitsample.CameraXViewModel
import net.simplifiedcoding.mlkitsample.R
import net.simplifiedcoding.mlkitsample.databinding.ActivityFaceDetectionBinding
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


class FaceDetectionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityFaceDetectionBinding
    private lateinit var cameraSelector: CameraSelector
    private lateinit var processCameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider
    private lateinit var cameraPreview: Preview
    private lateinit var imageAnalysis: ImageAnalysis

    private lateinit var btnCapture: Button
    private lateinit var preview_view: PreviewView


    private val cameraXViewModel = viewModels<CameraXViewModel>()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFaceDetectionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        cameraSelector =
            CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT).build()
        cameraXViewModel.value.processCameraProvider.observe(this) { provider ->
            processCameraProvider = provider
            bindCameraPreview()
            bindInputAnalyser()
        }
        btnCapture = findViewById(R.id.btnCapture)
        preview_view = findViewById(R.id.preview_view)


        btnCapture.setOnClickListener {
            captureImage()
        }

    }

    private fun captureImage() {
        val bitmap = preview_view.bitmap ?: return

        val imageFileName = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "$imageFileName.jpg")

        try {
            FileOutputStream(file).use { outStream ->
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream)
                outStream.flush()
                outStream.close()

                // Add the image to the gallery
                val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
                val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri)
                sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)

                // Show a toast or perform any other action to indicate the image has been saved
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    
    private fun bindCameraPreview() {
        cameraPreview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
            .build()
        cameraPreview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
        try {
            processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, cameraPreview)
        } catch (illegalStateException: IllegalStateException) {
            Log.e(TAG, illegalStateException.message ?: "IllegalStateException")
        } catch (illegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Log.e(TAG, illegalArgumentException.message ?: "IllegalArgumentException")
        }
    }

    private fun bindInputAnalyser() {
        val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(
            FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST)
                .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_NONE)
                .build()
        )
        imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
            .build()

        val cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor) { imageProxy ->
            processImageProxy(detector, imageProxy)
        }

        try {
            processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis)
        } catch (illegalStateException: IllegalStateException) {
            Log.e(TAG, illegalStateException.message ?: "IllegalStateException")
        } catch (illegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Log.e(TAG, illegalArgumentException.message ?: "IllegalArgumentException")
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun processImageProxy(detector: FaceDetector, imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val inputImage =
            InputImage.fromMediaImage(imageProxy.image!!, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
        detector.process(inputImage).addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
            binding.graphicOverlay.clear()
            faces.forEach { face ->
                val faceBox = FaceBox(binding.graphicOverlay, face, imageProxy.image!!.cropRect)
                binding.graphicOverlay.add(faceBox)
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            it.printStackTrace()
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            imageProxy.close()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = FaceDetectionActivity::class.simpleName
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            Intent(context, FaceDetectionActivity::class.java).also {
                context.startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want when I click on the button in the layout to take a photo and save it in the files, but the problem is that it's saving a black screen instead of the photo. How can I correct that ?